# Kauffman bracket polynomial algorithm

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I am doing a project on the invariants of knots and links specifically working on Kauffman bracket polynomial but drawing the states for knots with high crossings is tedious.
I am searching for a working code that can generate the states and the type of smoothings used.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi Martha, welcome to MO. I think your question might not misinterpreted as question about putting diagrams in a paper. Are you looking for something along these lines: http://katlas.org/wiki/The_Kauffman_Polynomial?

Answer (score 1):

[Bar-Natan's KnotTheory` Mathematica package](http://katlas.math.toronto.edu/wiki/The_Mathematica_Package_KnotTheory%60) can compute the Kauffman polynomial. If you need the actual state diagrams, I recommend looking [here](http://katlas.math.toronto.edu/wiki/The_Jones_Polynomial#How_is_the_Jones_polynomial_computed.3F)

Answer (score 1):

Sage has also some code about knots, but maybe not what you need.

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ SageMath version 9.1.beta1, Release Date: 2020-01-21               │
│ Using Python 3.7.3. Type "help()" for help.                        │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Warning: this is a prerelease version, and it may be unstable.     ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
sage: K = Knots()
sage: J = K.from_table(8,10)
sage: J.                 
         J.alexander_polynomial J.gauss_code           J.orientation          
         J.arcs                 J.genus                J.oriented_gauss_code  
         J.arf_invariant        J.homfly_polynomial    J.parent               
         J.base_extend          J.is_alternating       J.pd_code              
         J.base_ring            J.is_colorable         J.plot                 
         J.braid                J.is_idempotent        J.powers               
         J.cartesian_product    J.is_knot              J.regions              
         J.category             J.is_one               J.rename               
         J.colorings            J.is_zero              J.reset_name           
         J.connected_sum        J.jones_polynomial     J.save                 
         J.determinant          J.khovanov_homology    J.seifert_circles      
         J.dowker_notation      J.mirror_image         J.seifert_matrix       
         J.dt_code              J.n                    J.signature            
         J.dump                 J.number_of_components J.subs                 
         J.dumps                J.numerical_approx     J.substitute           
         J.fundamental_group    J.omega_signature      J.writhe
```

Comment: [The documentation for knots/links](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/knots/index.html) may be useful here.